# Fetching user details from AD

Tags: c#, active-directory

In my module I have a TextBox, Button and ListBox. Whenever button is pressed, I have to fetch the details of the user (fetched from the text box) and I need to add in the list box. This working now.

My problem is that if I press the button, the first time nothing happens - but if the same button is pressed a second time, I get the value of the user name in the list box.

Please help me identify the actual cause of why its not working on the first click. As of now I am clicking two times for every record.

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry entry1 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://corp.com", "123456", "password");           
        DirectorySearcher dSearch1 = new DirectorySearcher(entry1);           
        dSearch1.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samAccountName=" + Additional_ID.Text + "))";
        dSearch1.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        dSearch1.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        SearchResult result = dSearch1.FindOne();

        if (result.Properties["mail"] != null)
        {
            ListItem L = new ListItem();
            L.Text = "" + result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
            L.Value = "" + result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
            New_Users_list.Items.Add(L);
            Additional_ID.Text = "";
        }
        entry1.Close();
        dSearch1.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        Additional_ID.Text = "Enter Valid ID";
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, rather than calling `Close()` and `Dispose()` directly have a look at the `using` syntax which manages `IDisposable` instances on your behalf.

Comment: What happens while debugging/stepping your code the first time around (which don't work)? Do you get any error? You are trapping an exception with the try-catch block, and it does not say anything about what happened. Remove the try-catch, and post some stacktrace.

Comment: I am not getting any exception. For first time nothing is happening its Just postback the page.

Comment: Yes. This is ASP.NET webforms

Comment: What happens if you step through the Add_Click method the first time? Since nothing is happening, it's hard to know where to start from here. You do have a breakpoint on Add_Click? This get hit 1 time for each postback? On the second postback it does indeed return some result?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Facing same issue even after updating "using"